# Почему этот код работает не так как надо?

Tags: python, if, for

Это кусок из моего кода, почему-то он не работает, или работает не так, как надо. Этот код должен считать кол-во единиц в строке, но при выводе он всегда выводит "0".

```
cb = 0
for a in "1011":
    if a == 1:
        cb += 1
print(cb)
```

Comment: `s.count('1')`.

Comment: А так у вас несоответствие типов, 1 == '1' False, напишите `if a == '1':`

Comment: Потому что строка никогда не может быть равна числу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что при проходе по циклу у Вас в `a` будет сохранять символ строки `"1101"`, а сравнивать его будете с числом. Сравнивайте `a` c `'1'` либо приводите `a` к целому типу (`int(a)`), и проблема будет решена.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить переписанный код:

```
print('1011'.count('1'))
```